# Fedora 18 + Windows 8: Dual boot

Tags: linux, windows-8, fedora, uefi, grub2

I just bought a new notebook which came with Windows 8 (+UEFI) which I will use to play some games, however, I want to have Fedora (18) linux available for some stuff.

I tried and failed to install it in two different ways:

Using the available disk space, I created a `/boot`, a `/boot/efi` and a `/` partitions. This way, Fedora works just fine while grub is not able to start Win8 (it says it is because it can't find Microsoft's efi files).

Because of the previous situation, I then started using the default EFI partition as `/boot/efi`, so grub could be able to find all files needed. Instead of this, grub is now not even able to start Fedora normally.

Comment: Got it working by doing as suggested at: http://askubuntu.com/a/211077

Answer (score 1):

In your first installation, you could probably have repaired it by creating a custom /etc/grub.d/40_custom file. Something like the following should work, although creating GRUB 2 chainloader entries for EFI is a bit of an arcane art, so I can't make any promises:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Since you've moved on to the second installation, though, it's not clear what's going on because you've presented so little information. The `RESULTS.txt` file from a run of [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) would be useful, or at least a description of what precisely happens when you try to boot. Given the little information you've provided, the only solution I can suggest is to do a manual boot loader installation. [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can probably be made to work without too much struggle, but you'll need to boot an emergency system in EFI mode, mount your entire Fedora installation (including /boot and /boot/efi) somewhere, and use the `--root` option to `install.sh` to get it to install correctly.